# Parameter passing in Go

Tags: methods, parameter-passing, go

Suppose I have a method of type [`http.HandleFunc`](http://goneat.org/src/pkg/net/http/server.go?s=19626:19673#L674)

```
type HandlerFunc func(ResponseWriter, *Request)
```

And I want to wrap it around another method of the same type, somewhat like this:

```
func MyWrapper(res http.ResponseWriter, req *http.Request) {

    // do stuff

    AnotherMethod(res, req) // <- question refers to this line

    // do more stuff

}

func AnotherMethod(res http.ResponseWriter, req *http.Request) {

    // main logic

}
```

If I'm getting this right; when I call `AnotherMethod(res, req)` I'm passing a **copy** of (the value of) `res` to `AnotherMethod`, meaning that this object is now duplicated in memory.

Is there a way I could pass a **pointer** to `res` to `AnotherMethod` and then dereference there, in order to not copy the value of `res`? or am I not understanding something?

(Working with a pointer to (the value of) `res` inside `AnotherMethod` won't work because the receivers of all methods in `http.ResponseWriter` are values and not pointers)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[`http.ResponseWriter`](http://weekly.golang.org/pkg/net/http/#ResponseWriter) is an interface type. Which means it can be both a reference or value type, depending on what the underlying type is and how it implements the interface.

In this case, `res` is an instance of the unexported type `*http.response`. As you can see, it is a pointer type, which means you can pass it around without creating a copy of the whole structure.

To see what real type is held inside an interface value you are receiving, you can do this: `fmt.Printf("%T\n", res)`. It should print: `*http.resonse`.

For more information on how interface types work in Go, I recommend reading the [Go specification](http://weekly.golang.org/doc/go_spec.html#Interface_types) on the subject.